# How do I start Atom in safe mode on a mac?

Tags: macos, atom-editor

According to the [Atom Flight Manual](https://flight-manual.atom.io/hacking-atom/sections/debugging/#using-safe-mode), I should be able to start Atom in safe mode with `$ atom --safe` but the `atom` binary is not in my path. Nor can I locate it on the filesystem. The application folder has an `atom.sh` file but I get this message when I try to run it:

```
The application /Applications cannot be opened because its executable is missing.
```

I installed Atom using the mac package from https://atom.io/. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was that the executable is spelled with an uppercase "A". Not lowercase "atom" as they have in the manual. So this command worked:

```
$ /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/MacOS/Atom --safe
```

Edit: I just discovered that choosing "Atom" > "Install Shell Commands" from the menu will create the symlinks necessary for the `atom` command line application to work.